# Cx framework: How to set align:right and decimal precision on NumberField

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, number-formatting, cxjs

I am working on a project where IU is done in `Cx`, new `React` based Framework for FrontEnd. https://cxjs.io/
I have a Grid with filter Fields on top of each Column.
For example this is Number Column and Field:

```
{
    field: 'score', sortable: true,
    header: {
        style: 'width: 150px',
        items: <cx>
            <div>
                Score
                <br />
                <NumberField style="width:100%;margin-top:5px" value:bind="$page.filter.score"
                    reactOn="enter blur"/>
            </div>
        </cx>
    },
},
```

But value is on the left side, and I need it on the right.
I want both grid and filter field value to be on the right but keeping column name on the left. Like it is usually in Excel.
Also how to set custom number of decimal, 2 for example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NumberField` widgets allow setting additional styles on the input element through `inputStyle`. Formatting is done using `format`. Grid column headers can set its own styles using just `style`.

With all that in mind, it should be something like this:

```
{
    field: "score",
    sortable: true,
    header: {
      style: "width: 150px; text-align: left",
      items: (
        <cx>
          <div>
            Score
            <br />
            <NumberField
              value:bind="$page.filter.score"
              format="n;2"
              style="width:100%;margin-top:5px"
              inputStyle="text-align: right"
              reactOn="enter blur"
            />
          </div>
        </cx>
      )
    }
  }
```

Comment: Marko thx for quick reply.
One more thing, how could these components(field with it's header and NumberField) be overridden where this config would be set as default so that we don't have to repeat it for all Number column/fields.

Comment: @BorisDj You could extract header configuration into a function and call that function for each numeric column.